# Precise definition of "Primary Network Interface" on OSX

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, networking, mac-address

I'm considering using the MAC address as part of a machine identifier on OSX. The `GetPrimaryMACAddress.c` example on developer.apple.com demonstrates how to obtain the MAC address for the "primary" ethernet interface (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Listings/GetPrimaryMACAddress_GetPrimaryMACAddress_c.html). My question is "what is the precise definition of primary ethernet interface?" The comments describe it as the "built-in" network card. What happens on systems with more than one builtin interface? For example Mac Pros can have two wired plugs and older Macbook Pros have both a wired and wireless jack.

The only documentation I could find on this is the `IONetworkInterface.h` Reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Kernel/Reference/IONetworkInterface_header_reference/Reference/reference.html). It defines the `kIOPrimaryInterface` as describing "whether the interface is the primary or the built-in network interface." This doesn't answer my question about what happens when there are multiple builtin interfaces.

Comment: I don't know an official definition of primary network interface, but I'd guess that if there is one with a BSD name of "en0", you could treat that as primary.  Note that you can use functions from SystemConfiguration.framework to find the network addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's open source page located [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/IONetworkingFamily/IONetworkingFamily-100/IONetworkInterface.cpp)

I think you are looking for this specific code [/* Returns a Base-64 encoded MD5 hash of 'username:primary-mac-address' */](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/webdavfs/webdavfs-293.2/mount.tproj/EncodedSourceID.c?txt).

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns true if the receiver of this method is the system's primary
// network interface.

bool IONetworkInterface::isPrimaryInterface() const
{
    IOService * provider  = _driver;
    bool        isPrimary = false;

    if ( provider ) provider = provider->getProvider();

    // Look for the built-in property in the ethernet entry.

    if ( provider && provider->getProperty("built-in") && getUnitNumber() == 0)
    {
        isPrimary = true;
    }

    return isPrimary;
}
```

Comment: This looks to me like any ethernet card that isn't in a slot is primary, so you could have multiple primary interfaces. This contradicts a comment in the developer.apple.com example I mention in the question (they claim that you should only have one). I'm also concerned about that `ifdef __ppc__` macro. What about x86 (unless ppc is not referring to architecture here)? Also, from the copyright notice in the comments on the linked file it looks like this code might be quite old (that might explain the ppc thing).

Comment: Judging by the date of that code, it's not PowerPC as opposed to x86, it's PowerPC as opposed to Motorola 68K.  The code branch marked `__ppc__` might work for x86.

Comment: In case you have multiple built-in ports -> just "0" is the primary. In case you have wireless ethernet & ethernet -> you have 2 primaries. In the example code you loop through the results and grab the last one.

Comment: @xhruso00 Aha! So you can have more than one. Taking the last one doesn't seem like a great idea. I don't see anything to suggest that the ordering of this list is guaranteed. That case is easy to handle, though. Thanks!

Comment: @xhruso00 I didn't notice when I commented earlier today that you had updated the answer. The update answers my question: primary is the interface with unit number 0. We tested on a Mac Pro with two wired ethernet interfaces and one wireless. One of the wired interfaces was chosen as the primary (the machine was connected to the internet via the wireless interface).